# Choose the correct regression model

Tags: r, optimization, regression

The relation of two measurement values `x` and `y` might be

1. linear `mod1 <- lm(x~y)`
2. non-linear     `mod2 <- nlsLM(y ~ a - (a-b) * exp(-c*x))`
3. discarded

What selection criterion would you choose if you get the vectors `x` and `y` and know that 1.-3. are meaningful decisions for this measurements?

Models 1. and 2. might be compareablie with `AIC` or pseudo $R^2$?

Where is a useful for 3.?

Comment: 1 and 2 should be the other way round. I 've never heard of a discarded relationship between 2 variables. 1 and 2 are not comparable because they have a different dependent variable. I think first of all it is not clear what problem you are facing and secondly this is not a programming question...

Comment: @LyzandeR I've fixed the first issue. You can always test model performance against `mean(y)`, which would indicate no relationship to x.

Comment: @LyzandeR maybe something like "discarded if the fit from 1. and 2. is to bad" ... might be something like "Residual standard error < 0.9" in case 1. Because it is not really a statistic question, I hoped someone can help me here.

Comment: @ckluss You are wrong. This is a statistics question. Once you know what you want to do you can worry about implementing it in R. I've voted to migrate your question to the appropriate stack exchange site.

Comment: @ckluss: Agree this is a statistics question ( that might turn into a coding question after we see a better description and example dataset and more complete code.)  I think the statistics question will also need you to expand the description before the people at CrossValidated.com can comment. Describe the methods of data collection and the research question. Choosing among different models often requires knowledge of the costs and consequences of errors.